# Multiple triggers on the same event

Tags: triggers, rdbms

I would like to ask you which are the RDBMS's which support multiple triggers for the same event. For instance I have a table called MyTable and I would like to create trigger1 and trigger2 which should run before insert into the given table. Is there an RDBMS which supports this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need two triggers on the same "before insert" event? Can't you combine the trigger code into one?

Comment: Why do you need databases to store data? You can also store your data in files... But seriously, I need some dynamic event handling to automatically create events (in our case triggers) and I don't want to merge my events, because they are created, used and deleted automatically. Creating and deleting events will happen frequently, so it's not convenient at all to merge events.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Oracle, IBM-DB2 and MS-SQL all allow the creation of multiple triggers for the same event.

Comment: Thank You, Ron Tornambe. Your comment was more an answer than a comment, if you can edit your answer and put there the content of your comment I will accept your answer.